# If anchor tag contains href attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to play a jQuery animation when a user clicks on a menu link.

In my script, I prevent the default behavior of the link, save the value of the anchor tag's href attribute in a variable, play the animation, and then redirect the window to the URL corresponding to the saved href value:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.main-navigation a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = this.href;

    $('#main').slideUp(500,
    function() {
        window.location = href;
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The problem is, some of the anchor tags in my navigation menu do not have href attributes, because their only function is to open submenu on click. When I click on those menu items, the animation plays, and then the same page reloads.

I want to exclude the anchor tags that do not have href from the script's behavior.

My solution is to only save href for those anchor tags that actually have the href attribute. Except, I don't know how to do that.

**So, my question is:** how should I express this with jQuery?

```
if (anchor tag has href attribute) {
   var href = this.href;
}
```

Or perhaps there's a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$('.main-navigation a').click
```

Do :

```
$('.main-navigation a[href]').click
```

jQuery accept all CSS selector and even more!

Here the info for the [Bracket Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Thank you, Karl-Andre, this is a very elegant solution. I tried it now, and it works, but it made me notice another issue I wasn't aware of before. Clicking on the link to the current page also plays the animation, and then reloads the same page. Could you tell me, is there a way to also exclude current page, too?

Comment: My solution would be to add an id or class to the active link and the first line of the click function would be `if($(this).has('#yourId or .yourClass')) return false;`

Comment: Thank you, Karl-Andre - could you please explain to me how I can add class to the active link? I'm assuming, it should be done with JS, right?

Comment: Thanks, Karl-Andre – solved with PHP! However, the jQuery snippet you suggested seems to disable all the links. Argh... (Thanks!)

Comment: Did it. And for the jquery, I wasnt sure since I didnt tested. Anyway, PHP is alway the best tool for this kind of work!

Comment: I know, but what I mean is, I add `if($(this).has('.myClass')) return false;` and it disables all the links - how can I fix that?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, i gave you the wrong method, it is not `.has()` but `.is()`. Also, you put the class current on the parent, so the if condition should be `if($(this).parent().is('.myClass')) return false;`

Comment: I'm about to ask a few more jQuery question related to the same site though, @Karl-André - and would be grateful for your expertly insight.

Comment: Feel free to ask as much question as you want, as long as I am not doing your entire website at your place! Just dont post it in comment (this is not a chat forum). And i'm not exactly an expert, i'm still young and only have 3 years of experience. It's just that im good with logic things!

Comment: Nah, I wouldn't have you do my entire website for me, @Karl-André. Just the jQuery part. (Just kidding). Seriously though, here's another question I'm curious about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860709/change-the-speed-of-animation-depending-on-the-height-of-the-element

Comment: Sorry for returning to the old question that you already solved, @Karl-André. I realized I also need to exclude any external links from the entire behavior. On click, those links should just have the default behavior. How should I modify the script? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this : `$('.main-navigation a[href*='+window.location.hostname+']').click`

Comment: Nope, that one reverts all the links to default behavior, @Karl-André.

Comment: And this? `$('.main-navigation a[href*=\''+window.location.hostname+'\']').click`. It's kinda hard to find a solution on this one since I can't test it

Answer (score 3):

Just use an `if` to test the truthyness of your href:

```
var href = this.href;

if (href) {
  $('#main').slideUp(500,
  function() {
      window.location = href;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your selector to:

```
$('.main-navigation a[href]').click(function(event) {
```