# Change the speed of animation depending on the height of the element

Tags: jquery

I am sliding the content of my website's pages up with jQuery:

```
$('#main').slideUp(500);
```

This works okay, except there's noticeable difference in speed for individual pages, because some pages contain very little content (so `#main` is about 500px in height), while others have lots of content (and correspondingly, `#main` could be a 10000px in height).

So when 500px slide up in 500 milliseconds, it seems smooth and slow, but sliding 10000px up in the very same 500 milliseconds is like supersonic speed.

I think the solution should be using a variable for the speed parameter in parentheses that would reflect certain percentage of the height of the `#main`.

How can this be done?

Comment: have you tried the [UI's easing functions](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)? You might decide, e.g., that a quick start and a smooth landing are OK for you

Comment: They are ok, thanks, but that's not what I'm asking about, Walter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other said, i would use an algorithm to get the time. But i would also had a time limit since you probably don't want the 100000 px to take 10 sec to slide or the 200px to take 200ms.

Here's my solution:

```
var height = $('#main').height(),
    msPerHeight = 1, //How much ms per height
    minRange = 500, //minimal animation time
    maxRange = 1500, //Maximal animation time
    time = height * msPerHeight

time = Math.min(time, maxRange);
time = Math.max(time, minRange);

$('#main').slideUp(time)
```

Comment: Great thinking, @Karl-André, I love the idea of maxRange and minRange!

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuerys `$('#main').height()` for that:

```
 var height = $('#main').height();
 $('#main').slideUp((height / 500) * 500);
```

1. Get the height of #main
2. Divide it by 500(px) (because your said 500ms at 500px looks fine)
3. Multiply it by 500(ms)

Of course you might play arrount with the parameters :)

Comment: height() returns an integer no need to parse it

Comment: Except you removed the .height (?)

Comment: And then again height / 500 * 500 == height?

Comment: My cat did that, and yes, that depends on his specified 500px and 500ms - i know its kind of confusing

Comment: Hang on, so perhaps the proper way of doing it is just slideUp(1/height)? My logic begins to emit thick black smoke.

Comment: It has to be "the higher the height value, the slower the speed" – so what's the proper way of doing that?

Comment: No, that would be, "the more the height, the faster the speed", and the opposite is needed.

Comment: No, because the more the height, the more time it takes. Really i'm confused here

Comment: Sure, dividing by 500 and multiplying it again by 500 doesn't makes any sense, but thats just because you explained that it works best with 500ms duration on a 500px height (which means the effect should run at a speed of 1px per 1ms). but as the other answer points out, you should propably set a maximum duration - to avoid an almost endless effect on huge pages. He also used different numbers as you & me, propably to avoid such misunderstandings ;)

Comment: yeah. the fog ion my head has gradually cleared. Thanks a lot, @RienNeVaPlus

Answer (score 1):

jQuery calculates animation speed based on duration - the total time taken to complete the animation.  This is usually fine, but if it is more important for your animations to happen at the same speed (in pixels per second) than to happen in the same amount of time, you need to do the math for jQuery to convert rate to time.  Remember that equation from grade school?
*distance* = *rate* × *time* (or, in our case, *time* = *distance* ÷ *rate*)

```
var rate = 200; // pixels per second
var height = $("#main").height();
var ms = height / rate * 1000;
$("#main").slideUp(ms);
```

[play with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DF9t9/3/)